# Want to get the div object that is currently visible

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, viewport

On window scroll end I want to know which div is current visible to user?

How can i get the name of the div which is currently on the screen or you can say the div which is currently visible by user through jquery?

Comment: Why did you tag c#? Btw the keyword you are looking for is "*viewport*".

Answer (score 0):

Check the visibility of the div using it's id. Then retrieve the name of the div.

```
if($('#divId').is(':visible'))  
{  
   alert($('#divId').attr('name'));  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can apply a class on all the divs in the form, and loop through them.

```
$(".appliedClassName:visible").each(function(){
   alert($(this).attr('id'));
})
```

in place of alert you can get the div element and do whatever you want.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you want to display the last div visible in CURRENT VIEWPORT, try this:

```
$.fn.inView = function(){
    var win = $(window);
    obj = $(this);
    var scrollPosition = win.scrollTop();
    var visibleArea = win.scrollTop() + win.height();
    var objEndPos = (obj.offset().top + obj.outerHeight());
    return(visibleArea >= objEndPos && scrollPosition <= objEndPos ? true : false)
};


var lastelem;
$('div:visible').each(function(){
  if($(this).inView()){
    lastdiv = $(this);
  }
});
console.log(lastdiv);
```

OR
If you want to just know the last visible div on the window you can just use $('div:visible:last')

Answer (score 0):

Hi below code can help you

```
$( "div:visible").each(function () { 
   alert($(this)); 
 });
```

Comment: the [`:visible`](http://api.jquery.com/visible-selector/) selector does ***not*** distinguish between elements that are currently within the confines of the viewport and those that aren't.